# This simple left join operation doesn't work, but why?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am a bit confused about this simple mysql-query:

```
SELECT 
    `user`.`id`,
    `user`.`name`
 FROM 
    `#__users` `user`
 LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        `_s`.`userId`,
        SUM(`_s`.`fild12`) AS `fild12`,
        SUM(`_s`.`fild13`) AS `fild13`
     FROM 
        `#__logbookEventdata` `_s`
     GROUP BY `_s`.`userId`) `stats`
 ON 
    (`stats`.`userId`=`user`.`id`)
```

It returns this output:

```
id  | name
----+-------------
291 | bla
289 | Super User
290 | user1
```

actually I expected that the columns from *stats* would have been added to the output. But they weren't. When I simply call the stats-SELECT-query I get this output:

```
 userId | fild12 | fild13   
--------+--------+--------
289     |15      |0
290     |0       |0
```

I can't figure out why this doesn't work. I hope you guys can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: field that will appear in the output are defined in the `SELECT` part of the query.

Comment: Well, you didn't actually add anything from the `Stats` table to the `SELECT`...

Comment: you are not selecting them 'SELECT 
    `user`.`id`,
    `user`.`name`'
Those are the fields you are selecting if you want your subquery fields you need to select them as well in main select clause.

Comment: thanks a lot! it wokrs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the fields from `stats` to the main `select`:

```
SELECT 
    `user`.`id`,
    `user`.`name`,
    `stats`.*
FROM 
`#__users` `user`
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        `_s`.`userId`,
        SUM(`_s`.`fild12`) AS `fild12`,
        SUM(`_s`.`fild13`) AS `fild13`
     FROM 
        `#__logbookEventdata` `_s`
     GROUP BY `_s`.`userId`) `stats`
ON 
    (`stats`.`userId`=`user`.`id`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two set. First is user and second is stats. You multiple first to second. First all rows to second all rows.  If you change the set orders than not keep same result, because base rows (after from table) not equal as the joined rows (after left join subselect). The result keep all rows by from table/subquery.
I recommend you change transpose the two sets.